# Random number from 1 - 25 in java sequence

Tags: java, random, range

So I am trying to generate a random number, but I can't use the Java random function because I need the numbers to be in the range of 1-25. What is the easiest aka most efficient way of doing this? If possible, an explanation would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 25 + 1);
```

or

```
int random = new Random.nextInt(24) + 1;
```

Comment: I would use Random#nextInt instead. Floating point math scares me.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the [Java Random Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

```
import java.util.Random;
```

And then generate the random nuber like this - assuming you want an integer:

```
Random gen = new Random();
int r = gen.nextInt(25) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Random numbers between 1 and 25 (1-25)

```
Random.nextInt(24) + 1
```

Comment: That won't ever return 25.